# Firebase not defined with an AngularJS appservice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have ann application which I'm using angularJS for, and I want to integrate Firebase.

Within controllers I can easily write something like

```
var url = "http://myfirebaseuri";
var ref = new FireBase(url + Menu.title);
```

However, if I try the same thing from an angular service i get the following

ReferenceError: FireBase is not defined

Here's the code - does anyone have any ideas?

```
app.service('MenuModel', function () {

this.activeMenu = null;
var menus = [];

this.addMenu = function (Menu) {
    var url = "http://myfirebaseuri";
   var ref = new FireBase(url + Menu.title);
}
```

Comment: Try Firebase instead of FireBase?

Comment: Sometimes it really does help to have another set of eyes, thank you so much.

Comment: Exact same question, not the same solution... :(